# How to make diagonal divs like this?

Tags: html, image, diagonal

I was searching for diagonal divs and I didn't find anything that can help me. I have this project to do and I need to do this.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO99y.png)
[And This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cn7ZU.png)

I want to do exactly like that but I only find posts with horizontal diagonal divs..

Thanks, regards.

Edit: The second image link its the continuation from above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know nothing about diagonal divs but u can try to cover parts of img's that you need with

```css
.cover {
position: absolute;
top: -25px; /* or differenet position that fit on every section*/
left: 0;
z-index: 1;
width: 100vw;
height: 50px; /* or different height that you need*/
transform: rotate(-10deg); /* or different angle*/
background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover"></div>
```

And the same thing on bottom of section.

Be sure to set overflow and position on every section:

```css
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this easiest solution on the internet for making polygon shapes

You can use a CSS property `clip_path` to produce a shape of any type.

> > -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 33%,100% 10%,100% 60%,0 85%); This line represents that we are drawing polygon which has four points and specifying the
> > location of each point in terms of x and y. You can specify the
> > position in terms of `px, %` or any unit terminology

```
CSS Code
#header{
background-color:green;
height:350px;
width:100%;
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 33%,100% 10%,100% 60%,0 85%);
}
```

And

```
HTML Code
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="header">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And check this link, where I've written the same code just to illustrate the clip-path functionality, to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n1y4et70/6/)

For further and details Explanation check these links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path
- https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/

let me know if u didn't understand anything. I'll be more than happy to help you.